# Revert "z-index" in Raphael

Tags: canvas, z-index, raphael

I have a Raphael set() containing a text node and a circle. I'm using the toFront() method on the set to make sure all of the hovered elements are visible.

However, when the mouse leaves the element I'd like it to return the elements to their initial "z-index", which I suppose I do using either insertBefore() or insertAfter(). But how do I know where to reinsert the elements? And is there a method I can use on the set() which will do this for all its elements, or do I need to write  acustom method?

On a related note, I'm storing the set as a property of a javascript object

```
this.marker = this.canvas.set()
```

But this.marker isn't showing up at all in firebug, despite attr changes triggered by the hover (and dependant on finding .marker via the parent object) happening consistently. Does anyone knwo why this.marker isn't showing up in the dom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track off the z-index. zindex++ for every raphäel you create. Then save the original z-index for the object you move around in the index-hierarchy.

Also try insertBefore() on the set. Should work. I kept a huge amount of objects in a set and had to move them all around at the same time (http://www.ichbinadrian.ch) and set.translate() worked fine with me.